# changing a button's image

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm planning to make a sound button, and for the button I have two images: one for ENABLE and one for DISABLE state for sound.

I just set first image `@"onimage"` for button and set a boolean `SoundIsOn=YES` on `viewDidLoad`. The button apears.

I added an action method to call upon button clicks.

```
[soundBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the `switchSound` method, I check if the `SoundIsOn` is `YES` or `NO`, and I want to change the button image to make the sound enable and disable. But the button's image isn't changing.

Here is my code for `switchSound`:

```
if  (soundIsOn == YES) {
        [self.soundBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        soundIsOn = NO;
    }
    if  (soundIsOn == NO) {
        [self.soundBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        soundIsOn = YES;
    }
```

Question : how can i change button image after every click? any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to set two states for the button. Selected and Normal. On  `switchSound ` method do: `self.soundBtn.selected = !self.soundBtn.selected` http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/04/16/uibutton-control-states/

Comment: thanks for your help :)  it worked really nice. and if i want to have sound enabled and disabled i have to check if(sound.button.selected) to performselector and vise versa?

Comment: where can i vote your comment? :)

Comment: I cant vote comment coz there is no arrow. just answer what u commented then i can vote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.soundBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offimage"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.soundBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


- (IBAction)switchSound:(id)sender
{
    self.soundBtn.selected = !self.soundBtn.selected;
    soundIsOn = !soundIsOn;
}
```

Of course, you coulв change images at the Interface Builder (if you are using it).